# Need help on app-route element of polymer implemented in .net core mvc application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, polymer, asp.net-core-mvc, app-router

I'm implementing polymer's app-route element in .net core mvc application.

The folder structure is :

-project

```
  --wwwroot folder  
    ---bower_components  
    ---Components  
       ----page1 folder  
            -page1.html  
       ----page2 folder  
            -page2.html  
       ----scaffold folder
            -src
              -header.html
            -scaffold.html
```

I have implemented scaffolding with the help of app-layout element of polymer.
I have displayed tabs in the header section using the iron-selector, which when clicked redirects the user to the selected tab's appropriate page.
I have also used iron pages where-in the components have been referred.All this code is there in the header.html file.

I 'm facing issues/confused with the app-route part.exactly what path shall i give in the pattern attribute.

Below is my code :

```
   <app-location route="{{route}}"></app-location>
    <app-route route="{{route}}"
               pattern="/Components/:page"
               data="{{routeData}}"
               tail="{{subroute}}"></app-route>


    <iron-selector selected="[[page]]" attr-for-selected="data-page">
        <a data-page="rewards" href="/rewards">TLG REWARDS</a>
        <a data-page="earnpoints" href="/earnpoints">EARN POINTS</a>
        <a data-page="redeempoints" href="/redeempoints">REDEEM POINTS</a>
    </iron-selector>

    <iron-pages selected="[[page]]" attr-for-selected="name" 
       fallback-selection="view404" role="main">
        <pointbank-rewards name="rewards"></pointbank-rewards>
        <pointbank-earnpoints name="earnpoints"></pointbank-earnpoints>
        <pointbank-redeempoints name="redeempoints">
        </pointbank-redeempoints>
    </iron-pages>
```

Please help!!!

Regards
rizie

Comment: The pattern of an app-route elements is matched against the actual URL. What is your URL?

Comment: And I just realized that your databinding references `page`. This should probably be `routeData.page`.

Comment: I want to use app-route within folders.

Comment: The pattern of the app-route element needs to match the current URL. Without knowing, what the URL is, we can't tell you what value the pattern needs to have.